# How to create PCM signed 16 bit wav file

Tags: c++, wav

I have a  binary binary file of raw audio streams.I want to create a wav file with properties PCM signed 16 bit mono little endian with the sample rate 22050hz.

Currently am using the below code:

```
template <typename T>
void write(std::ofstream& stream, const T& t) {
    stream.write((const char*)&t, sizeof(T));
}

template <typename SampleType>
void writeWAVData(const char* outFile, SampleType* buf, size_t bufSize,
                  int sampleRate, short channels)
{
    std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::binary);
    stream.write("RIFF", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);
    stream.write("WAVE", 4);
    stream.write("fmt ", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 16);
    write<short>(stream, 1);                                        // Format (1 = PCM)
    write<short>(stream, channels);                                 // Channels //mono/sterio
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate); 

    write<int>(stream, sampleRate * channels * sizeof(SampleType)); // Byterate
    write<short>(stream, channels * sizeof(SampleType));            // Frame size
    write<short>(stream, 16 * sizeof(SampleType));                   // Bits per sample
    stream.write("data", 4);
    stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);
    stream.write((const char*)buf, bufSize);
}


int wmain(int argc,wchar_t **argv)
{
    std::ifstream is("c:\\stream", std::ios_base::binary);
    if (is) {
        // get length of file:
        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);
        char * buffer = new char [length];
        is.read (buffer,length);
        writeWAVData("c:\\audio.wav", buffer, length, 22050, 1);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong here?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? A compile error? A runtime error? Unexpected output?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Guys you are right .Here is my final working code

```
template <typename T>
void write(std::ofstream& stream, const T& t) {
    stream.write((const char*)&t, sizeof(T));
}

template <typename SampleType>
void writeWAVData(const char* outFile, SampleType* buf, size_t bufSize,
                  int sampleRate, short channels)
{
    std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::binary);
    stream.write("RIFF", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);
    stream.write("WAVE", 4);
    stream.write("fmt ", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 16);
    write<short>(stream, 1);                                        // Format (1 = PCM)
    write<short>(stream, channels);                                 // Channels //mono/sterio
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate); 

    write<int>(stream, sampleRate * channels * sizeof(SampleType)); // Byterate
    write<short>(stream, channels * sizeof(SampleType));            // Frame size
    write<short>(stream, 8 * sizeof(SampleType));                   // Bits per sample
    stream.write("data", 4);
    uint32_t sz = bufSize;
    stream.write((const char*)&sz, 4);
    stream.write((const char*)buf, bufSize);
}


int wmain(int argc,wchar_t **argv)
{
    FILE *fhandle=fopen("c:\\stream","rb");
    seek(fhandle, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
    int length ; = ftell(fhandle); // get current file pointer
    fseek(fhandle, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
    length = length * 16;
    short* Data=new short [length]; // Create an element for every sample
fread(Data,16/8,length/(16/8),fhandle);//read data
    writeWAVData("c:\\audio.wav", buffer, length, 22050, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By passing a `char*` pointer as the `buf` argument, the sample type is deduced as `char`. If the samples are actually 16 bits, then the values depending on `sizeof(SampleType)` will be wrong.

You could cast to `short*`; but it might be better to remove the templatiness and pass the sample size as another runtime parameter. In either case, you should multiply by 8 (or `CHAR_BIT`), not 16, to get the number of bits.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems I see are:

1. `buffer` needs to be `short*` or `int16_t*` in order to have `SampleType` be 16 bits.
2. `write<short>(stream, 16 * sizeof(SampleType));` should be `write<short>(stream, 8 * sizeof(SampleType));` when writing bits per sample.
3. `stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);` is not doing the right thing if `size_t` is not 4 bytes (it's usually 8 bytes on 64-bit systems) since you are basically chopping off the first 4 bytes of `bufSize` and writing them.  You need to static_cast to a 32-bit integer first:

   ```
   uint32_t sz = bufSize;
   stream.write((const char*)&sz, 4);
   ```

There may be other issues, but those are the glaring ones to me.